# How many ways can a rook move from the top left to the bottom right corner. How do you generalize a formula for this.

Tags: combinatorics, combinations, chessboard

A game of chess is played on a board with 64 squares. generalize a formula for how many ways the rook could move from the top left to the bottom right corner. I know how to write the formula for example if it could only move 1 space at a time. the answer would be (M+N)C(N) M as in the number of ways left and N as in the the number of ways down. But how do you write a formula for if you could move say 1,2,3 etc spaces at a time. Would you write formulas for each one then add them together?

thanks

Comment: Are you assuming that it can move only to the right and down, never up or to the left?

Comment: Yes, so only moving towards the bottom right corner

Comment: So you are talking about a [Staircase Walk](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/StaircaseWalk.html), but instead of being able to move **one** step at a time, you can move **any** number of steps at a time?

Comment: Esssentially yes. But now you can also move in different directions while the staircase you can only move straight up.

Comment: On a regular chess board I can move from the upper left to the upper right in one $7$-space step or in $7$ $1$-space steps; do you want to consider those distinct paths?

Comment: @b0ng4L33: The castle can only move vertically and horizontally, so you still just get staircase walks; the only question is whether you want to count separately a segment that is traversed all at once and one that is traversed in several shorter segments.

Comment: http://oeis.org/A051708

Comment: Yes it can move any number of spaces down or right

Comment: Yes it is basically still a staircase walk but now it takes many more factors into account such as different number of spaces and direction. But I don't know how to put this into formula.

Comment: @b0ng4L33: You’ve said enough that I can guess the answer, but you still haven’t actually answered the crucial question: is moving $2$ squares to the right in one move considered different from moving $2$ squares to the right in $2$ moves of one space each?

Comment: Yes moving 2 squares to the right is one move while moving is different from moving two squares to the right in 2 moves of one space each

Comment: so an example of way it could move is (2 right{this is one move}),(1 down), (1 right), (3 down{this is also one move}), (4 right{one move}) and then (4 down{1 move}). This is a possible sequence that could be done.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott any suggestions?

Comment: [This PDF](http://zimmer.fresnostate.edu/~khangt/Rook-Queen.pdf) derives a recurrence, a generating function, and a formula in the form of a double summation of a product of three binomial coefficients. **bof**’s link above has information and references for the case $m=n$, and [this paper](https://www.combinatorics.org/ojs/index.php/eljc/article/view/v19i1p57) gives a combinatorial proof of a recurrence for that case.